# Overlaying an image on a point, on a map in sharpmap?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharpmap

I can add points to a map but I want to show an image (like a baloon or location sign) instead of the default red circle for the points.
how can I do that with Sharpmap?
my code to draw points is:

```
    Dim vlay2 As New VectorLayer("Points")
    Dim geomColl As New Collection(Of GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry)()
    'Get the default geometry factory
    GeoAPI.GeometryServiceProvider.Instance = New NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices()
    Dim gf As GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometryFactory = GeoAPI.GeometryServiceProvider.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory()

    geomColl.Add(gf.CreatePoint(New GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)))
    vlay2.DataSource = New SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(geomColl)
    Mapbox1.Map.Layers.Add(vlay2)
    Mapbox1.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found My answer.
we can do that by using:

```
    Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("D:\Desktop\Pics\compass.png")
    vlay2.Style.Symbol = img
    Mapbox1.Map.Layers.Add(vlay2)
```